# How to exclude a CActiveRecord property from filtering with CGridView in Yii?

Tags: php, yii, cgridview, yii-cactiverecord, cactiverecord

In a Yii 1.1 application I'm displaying the data a table using the `CGridView`.

```
$dataProvider = $model->search();
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'id' => 'my-grid',
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filter' => $model,
    'columns' => array(
        'id',
        'user.firstname',
        'user.lastname',
        'user.email',
        'type',
        'foo', // <-- on-the-fly added attribute
        'bar', // <-- on-the-fly added attribute
        ...
    ),
));
```

Curretly all columns of model's table (`id`, `type`) and even the on-the-fly added attributes (`foo`, `bar`) get a filter input field. (The filters of the additional properties don't work.)

I want to have filters for only some of the fields, e.d. `id` and `tipe`. **How can I enable only the filters I need / disable the filters I don't need?**

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution, that looks like a workaround -- just do define the not filtered properties explicitly and set the `filter` parameter for each one to `false`:

```
...
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'id' => 'my-grid',
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filter' => $model,
    'columns' => array(
        'id',
        ...
        'type',
        array(
            'name' => 'foo',
            'filter' => false,
        ),
        array(
            'name' => 'bar',
            'filter' => false,
        ),
        ...
    ),
));
```

It works, but I think, there should be a more elegant solution...